# Django Rest Framework: make a field not required in modelviewset create

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model which have got a field for showing time it created, named `created_time`. I don't want `created_time` to be required when creating model, but I want it to be in retrieved data from model!

This is its serializer:

```py
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['name', 'created_time']
```

And this is its viewset:

```py
class ModelApiView(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user.id)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user, created_time=datetime.now())
```

Right now, by `get` request it sends a list of Model objects with `name` and `created_time` which is perfect. But when I post a new Model to be created, containing just its `name`, it sends me this error message:

```json
{
    "datetime": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can add `created_time = serializer.DateTimeField(required=False)` in the top of the `ModelSerializer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make the field not required by specifying that in the `ModelSerializer`:

```
class MyModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_time = serializer.DateTimeField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'created_time']
```